# Resin forming thin layer on bottom of vat (sludgelike)

Tags: resin, anycubic-photon

I have just bought the Anycubic Photon Mono X and I am having some trouble. I was wondering if anyone else ever had this issue.

The resin seems to be hardening on the bottom of the vat after I cleaned it and tried to do a print. This sometimes happens as well if I leave the resin in the vat overnight. I usually keep the temperature in the room around 70 F, I am not sure if that matters.

Here are my settings:

- Layer Height: 0.03 mm
- Bottom Layer Count: 6
- Exposure Time: 4 s
- Light-off Delay: 0.5 s
- Bottom Light-off Delay: 0.5 s
- Bottom Lift Distance: 8 mm
- Lifting Distance: 8 mm
- Bottom Lift Speed: 180 mm/min
- Lifting Speed: 180 mm/min
- Retract Speed: 240 mm/min

[image: Photo of resin in a vat that has turned to sludge]

I don’t store the printer open. It’s not exposed to any UV from light or windows. I'm not sure about the resin settling on the ground as I shake it before every use

Comment: Are your prints failing or coming out badly?

Answer (score 1):

this happens when you print and the resin does not adhere well to the lift platform. This way the print stays at the bottom.
The first layer builds up between the FEP sheet (bottom of vat) and the build platform. If you are lucky, the connection to the build pltform is stronger than the FEP sheet. A couple of things affect the adhesion to both surfaces:

- FEP sheet tension (don't tension too tight, not too loose)
- FEP sheet cleanliness (lightly coat with silicon grease)
- build platform cleanliness (clean with alcohol)
- build platform height (should be exactly on the bottom of vat at home position)
- build platform alignment (should be exactly flat compared to bottom of vat)
- lift speed (lifting too fast with a big print can make the print come loose from the bed)
- cure time (curing the first layers too short can make the adhesion worse)